# foreach loop - only updates last with last row variables

Tags: php, loops

I am retrieving JSON-data by a loop and like to update some of the variables in my database. Problem is, that only the variables of the last row in the loop are being stored. Here is the simplified code:

```
foreach($json['events'] as $events){

   $id       = $events['id'];
   $variable = $events['name'];
   echo $variable;                //just to test

   $db->query(" UPDATE Table SET Column = '$variable' WHERE id = '$id' ");

}
```

When I echo the $variable it gets me the correct output in the loop. But when I want to uptade the variable in the database, only the value of the last row of the loop is being used.

What is wrong with my code?

Comment: can you `echo $id` as well?

Comment: Yes, the id is unique and it echos correctly for every single row in the foreach-loop .

Comment: Do you mind sharing the results/output?

Comment: your `$id` are unique, but do you have rows with these ids in your database?  You are doing an UPDATE, not an INSERT, so the id must exist first.

Comment: Yes, a row is existing already. The code above is just shortened to focus on the main problem.

Comment: Sorry, false alarm. The code above is correct. The mistakes is way before the code. Can this topic be deleted?